# Forward traffic server to another server with iptable and domain

Tags: iptables, nat, tunnel

I want to forward all traffic from server1 to server2 with domain
same:

```
sysctl net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 22 -j DNAT --to-destination IpServer1
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -j DNAT --to-destination DomainServer2
iptables -t nat -A POSTROUTING -j MASQUERADE
```

but output:
Bad IP address iptables -t nat

Comment: `iptables` doesn't do domains. It's - as implied by name -  a IP filtering system. It doesn't know or care about DNS.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I need a reverse proxy solution for SSH](https://serverfault.com/questions/226952/i-need-a-reverse-proxy-solution-for-ssh)